# Substring search in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a problem with string comparison. For example, there is this string:

```
"hello world i am from heaven"
```

I want to search if this string contains "world". I used following functions but they have some problems. I used `String.indexof()` but if I will try to search for "w" it will say it exists.

In short I think I am looking for exact comparison. Is there any good function in Java?

Also is there any function in Java that can calculate log base 2?

Comment: @agazerboy - Don't put two totally unrelated questions into one Question.

Comment: So in the "w" case you are expecting something that returns false because it isn't a complete word?

Answer (score 27):

I'm assuming the problems you're having with `indexOf()` related to you using the character version (otherwise why would you be searching for w when looking for world?). If so, `indexOf()` can take a string argument to search for:

```
String s = "hello world i am from heaven";
if (s.indexOf("world") != -1) {
  // it contains world
}
```

as for log base 2, that's easy:

```
public static double log2(double d) {
  return Math.log(d) / Math.log(2.0d);
}
```

Comment: I explode every string to do some kind of comparison for my application. Some time it also get single CHAR so it create these problems. If i want to pass argument by myself then i know i can pass a string. But that is at run time. Can you please another solution ?

Comment: Or you can also say that I am looking for organization in a string and at run time it get the arugment "or" again it will say YES EXIST

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Can you explain?

Answer (score 9):

For an exact String comparison, you can simply do:

```
boolean match = stringA.equals(stringB);
```

If you want to check that a string contains a substring, you can do:

```
boolean contains = string.contains(substring);
```

For more String methods, see the [javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
String s = "hello world i am from heaven";
if (s.contains("world")) {
// This string contains "world"
}
```

This is a simple and easy-to-use function and for a one-liner:

```
String s = "hello world i am from heaven";
if (s.contains("world")) System.out.prinln("It exists!!!!!!!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi My version is as below:

```
package com.example.basic;

public class FindSubString {


    public String findTheSubString(String searchString, String inputString){


        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(inputString);

        System.out.println("The capacity of the String " + builder.capacity());

        System.out.println("pos of" + builder.indexOf(searchString));

        return builder.substring(builder.indexOf(searchString),builder.indexOf(searchString)+searchString.length());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String myString = "Please find if I am in this String and will I be found";
        String searchString = "I am in this String";

        FindSubString subString = new FindSubString();

        boolean isPresent = myString.contains(searchString);

        if(isPresent){

        System.out.println("The substring is present " + isPresent + myString.length());

        System.out.println(subString.findTheSubString(searchString,myString));
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("The substring is ! present " + isPresent);

        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution finally.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayTemplist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        String searchString = mEditText.getText().toString();
                        if(searchString.equals("")){new DownloadJSON().execute();}

                    else{


                    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                        String currentString = arraylist.get(i).get(MainActivity.COUNTRY);
                        if (searchString.toLowerCase().contains(currentString.toLowerCase())) {
    //pass the character-sequence instead of currentstring

                            arrayTemplist.add(arraylist.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                        }
                        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayTemplist);
                        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                }


            });
    }
```

**Replace the above code with this one:**

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayTemplist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        String searchString = mEditText.getText().toString();
                        if(searchString.equals("")){new DownloadJSON().execute();}

                    else{


                    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                        String currentString = arraylist.get(i).get(MainActivity.COUNTRY);
                        if (currentString.toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
    //pass the character-sequence instead of currentstring

                            arrayTemplist.add(arraylist.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                        }
                        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayTemplist);
                        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                }


            });
```

Comment: It's better when you also explain what you have changed in the new code and why it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a below string:

```
String sampleS = "hello world i am from heaven";
```

Use below code for String to String comparison:

```
boolean is_Equal = sampleS.equals("<any string you want to compare>");
```

Use either of below code to check if your string contains a substring:

```
boolean is_Contains = sampleS.contains("world");
// OR
boolean is_Contains = (sampleS.indexOf("world") != -1);
```